# AEM5.6 | Select all implementation for dialog

Tags: aem

I am trying to implement Select-all checkbox in Component dialog. 
On selecting/checking select-all checkbox, all other check-boxes should be checked & on deselecting/unchecking select-all checkbox, all other check-boxes should be unchecked.

[image: Dialog]

The listener code I wrote is

```
function()
{   
    var type = this.getValue();
    var flag = true;


    if(type==''){
        flag = false;
    }
    if(!flag){
        this.findParentByType('dialog').getField('./pricingVividBlack').defaultValue = false;
    }
    else{
        this.findParentByType('dialog').getField('./pricingVividBlack').defaultValue = true;
    }

}
```

Please help me rectify my code to achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this based on your dialog structure.

If the tabpanel / panel contains only the above checkboxes and selecting/deselecting should enable / disable all of them, then the following code should do the trick.

```
function(field, val, isChecked) {
    var panel = field.findParentByType('panel');
    var selections = panel.findByType('selection');

    if (isChecked) {
        CQ.Ext.each(selections, function() {
            if (this.isCheckbox) {
            this.setValue(true);
            }
        });
    } else {
        CQ.Ext.each(selections, function() {
            if (this.isCheckbox) {
            this.setValue(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Or, you set an extra property to identify only those fields that needs this behavior and you can use that property to identify them using the above code and enabled or disabled them accordingly.

For more understanding, refer to [CQ5 Widget API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection)